# boost::algorithm::contains std::vector<long> & long value

Tags: c++, boost, contains

I am using `boost::algorithm::contains(std::vector<long>, long value)` and receiving a host of errors.

```
std::vector<long> instance;
long byteIndex;
// (Perhaps more code?...)
boost::algorithm::contains(instances, byteIndex);
```

I don't understand this compiler error `C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'boost::range_const_iterator<C>'`.

I read the template class and saw a demonstration using std::string

```
std::string s = "Boris Schäling"; 
boost::algorithm::contains(s, "is");
```

I do not consider my use of boost's contains any different except I am using a different type.  Any idea why `boost::algorithm::contains(std::vector<long>, long)` won't compile?

Comment: Please show the code causing this error.

Comment: `boost::algorithm::contains(std::vector<long>, long)` is the code causing the error.  An attempt to compile that causes the error with an additional statement `see reference to function template instantiation 'bool boost::algorithm::contains<std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>,long>(const Range1T &,const Range2T &)' being compiled`.  From the perspective of the template, I do not see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please actually show the code, don't just describe it.

Comment: @KyleLutz `boost::algorithm::contains(instances, byteIndex)` is the code whereby `instances` is a std::vector<long> and `byteIndex` is a long. This is a template function call so there is nothing more to show.

Comment: there is a lot more you could show. providing an actual compilable example that demonstrates your problem would be much more helpful. with what you've provided we're all just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::algorithm::contains` expects two ranges, the input range and the range to search for. You're getting an error because you're providing the first range (`std::vector<long>`) but not the second (you only give a single `long` value).

You'd be better off using `std::find`:

```
std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), value) != vector.end()
```

Comment: I dislike std::find for this implementation because it does not return a bool but an iterator to the object found and would unnecessarily bloat the code.  This is why I wanted `boost::algorithm::contains` because it allows most closely an equivalence of [Vector.contains in Java.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) All I need do is `std::vector<long>(byteIndex)` and the comparison will work.  Not quite the most elegant but gets the job down.

Comment: @DrewDormann The correction is `std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), value) != vector.end()`?

Comment: @KyleLutz Discovered another error in `boost::algorithm::compare.hpp` in which the compiler dislikes `error C2679: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const char'` based on performing a `boost::algorithm::contains(std::vector<std::string>, "null")`.

Comment: @Mushy: i think you're misunderstanding what `boost::algorithm::contains` does. would you expect `std::string("hello") == 'h'` to compile?

Comment: @KyleLutz I understand the point you are making; all compiles well now.

Answer (score 1):

`boost::algorithm::contains` takes two ranges. You are searching for a value in your vector.

In your string example, you are searching for the sequence `"is"`. If you were to search for `'i'` (not a sequence, a value), you would get the same error as you are describing with your `vector<long>`.

The code:

```
std::vector<long> v { 1,2,3,4,5 };
std::vector<long> v1 { 3, 4 };
boost::algorithm::contains(v, v1);
```

compiles just fine.